# Корреляционный код в С++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Есть задача, с бинарной системы исчисления провести корреляцию, то есть с `1001` должно выйти `10010110`. Каждая единица это 10, а ноль это 01. Я написал/нашел программу на, консольной на С++ котороя делает это

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Enter a binary code\n";
    std::cin >> str;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if (str[i] == '1')  str.insert(++i, "0");
        else str.insert(++i, "1");
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

А вот мне постучали по голове и сказали что надо сделать в winforms на том же С++. Пытаясь перевести это всё на форму я столкнулся с проблемами

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


    String^ str = textBox1->Text;

    for (int i = 0; i < str->Length; i++)
        if (str[i] == '1')  str->Insert(++i, "0");
        else str->Insert(++i, "1");

    textBox2->Text = str;

    }
```

На кнопку я повесил обработчик который должен сразу выводить конечный результат, но выводит вводимое число, как так, и что я делаю неправильно?
Вроде как по логике сначала происходит операция а потом пере-инициализация.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str->Insert` не изменяет объект `str`, а только возвращает результат.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str->Length; i++)
    if (str[i] == '1') str = str->Insert(++i, "0");
    else str = str->Insert(++i, "1");
```

Comment: а подскажите как дать этой переменной число с параметрами, если я правильно выразился?

Comment: что значит число с параметрами?

Comment: str->Insert(++i, "1");  то что я передаю что делать с переменной

Comment: так я же написал присвоение в коде

Comment: а, извинте, я как раз проверил когда вы написали, на взгляд я отличий не нашел. Сейчас вникну что изменили. За ответ огромное спасибо

Comment: всё, понял что произошло, чет не додумался. Еще раз мои благодарствия